# encoding error while using np.matrix and np.chararray

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am building a Flask website in Spanish for people to send via mail encoded messages. Basically, you paste your text in a textfield and it returns its encoded version. The functions encode() and decode() below function OK until it deals with accentuated and other non-standard characters. My default system encoding is 'ascii', and I believe the problem may arise by me using numpy.matrix and numpy.chararray which might change the encoding of my string.

When I build the code and test below in Sublime Text 2 I get a:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3'... but no encoding declared;
see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

When I add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the code it runs in ST2, but it also spits an error and the decoded message is missing certain characters like so:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]

La cr  a del le  n tiene dos a  os.
```

When I run it in a local server with Flask i get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried the chardet package and the items in the matrix are recognized as 'windows-1252'. I decode the items in the matrix using 'windows-1252' and 'cp1252' but the problems persists. I tried encoding with 'utf-8' after the previous decoding (i.e. with 'windows-1252') but it doesn't work. I suspect this is an encoding problem, but I am not entirely sure. Any leads on how to solve this are very much appreciated.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import random, string, re

def encode(message, size, token):
        """Assumes message is a string, size is the size limit of the message,
        and token is a string with unique characters, i.e. bufalo but not rana"""

        message = list(message)

        while len(message) < size:
            sgn = random.choice(['*', '?', '&', '@'])
            message.append(sgn)

        matrix = np.matrix(message)
        cols = size/5

        matrix = matrix.reshape((cols, 5)).T
        encoded = np.chararray(shape=(cols,5)).T

        token = token.lower()
        token = list(token)
        new = []
        for i in token:
            new.append(sorted(token).index(i))

        while len(new) > 5:
            for i in new:
                if i >= (5):
                    new.remove(i)

        old = range(0,5)

        for o, n in zip(old, new):
            encoded[np.ix_([n], range(0, matrix.shape[1]))] = matrix[np.ix_([o], range(0, matrix.shape[1]))]

        encoded_str = ''
        for i in range((encoded.size)):
            encoded_str += encoded.item(i)

        return encoded_str

#########################################
#THIS IS A TEST
#########################################
mssg = "La cría del león tiene dos años."
print encode(mssg, 120, 'bufalo')
#########################################

def decode(message, size, token):
        message = list(message)

        while len(message) < size:
            sgn = random.choice(['*', '?', '&', '@'])
            message.append(sgn)

        matrix = np.matrix(message)

        cols = size/5
        matrix = matrix.reshape((5, cols))

        token = token.lower()
        token = list(token)
        new = []
        for i in token:
            new.append(sorted(token).index(i))
        while len(new) > 5:
            for i in new:
                if i >= (5):
                    new.remove(i)
        old = range(0,5)

        decoded = np.chararray(shape=(cols,5)).T
        for n, o in zip(old, new):
            decoded[np.ix_([n], range(0, matrix.shape[1]))] = matrix[np.ix_([o], range(0, matrix.shape[1]))]

        decoded =decoded.T

        decoded_str = ''
        for i in range((decoded.size)):
            decoded_str += decoded.item(i)

        decoded_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', decoded_str)
        return decoded_str
```

Comment: Maybe try defining your string like: `u'La cría del león tiene dos años.'` — it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you need to do to fix the code

1) Since you code contains unicode characters, it makes sense to add `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

2) The test string should be a unicode string. So the line should become

```
mssg = u"La cría del león tiene dos años."
```

3) The `encoded` array (from the line `encoded = np.chararray(shape=(cols,5)).T`) is default to ascii string. You should change the line to

```
encoded = np.chararray(shape=(cols,5), unicode=true).T
```

i.e. you need to add parameter **`unicode=true`**

Then the code will run and print this result

```
lt a?@&*@*&&&*&*&*?&?*Lílnnss&*@&&*@&??&?&@**?aa  e .@?*@&&@?@?*@?@?&?cdeidñ*&??&?**@*@*@&*&?@reóeoo&**&?@?&&??&@@??&&
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I was able to solve the problem in Sublime Text 2 by making the two changes suggested AND adding  decoded_str = decoded_str.encode("utf-8") right before the end of the decode() function. I addtionally had to get rid of decoded_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', decoded_str) and instead I used the replace method from string to remove ['*', '?', '&', '@'] (after the utf-8 encoding). To make it work on Flask I removed the final utf-8 encoding and kept the new replacement method because I got a UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: Nice to know! If my answer resolved your issue, please kindly accept it.

Comment: Do you know if the reason this worked in Flask but not in ST2 has to do with the two of them using different default encodings? I believe decoded_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', decoded_str)  was stripping the unicode of important characters and thus when printing it omitted accents and other special characters.

Comment: Sorry, not an expert of sublime text